why can't matplotlib show picture in a project (after running, only a window pops up.), but in other projects it works well?
Under one project, after running the code, only a figure window pops up, without any picture, if I close it , it will pops up a.
notice
But in other projects, if I run the same code, matplotlib works well. I think the code it's right. there must be something wrong with the pycharm or the project. How do I solve it?

You could try import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('tkagg') to change the backend.

Several things could cause the problem that you described. Different projects can have different run configurations.
Can you check whether the run configuration is the same for the project with the problem, and the project(s) where the code is working?
Can you check whether you are using the latest version of PyCharm? It could be a bug or something.
P.S. it would be helpful if you posted your code and your project hiearchy, as I am suspecting a problem somewhere within the project.
